# Merge tracking data from multiple sources

Tags: general-topology

I have a data set collected from multiple devices on a vehicle. Each device is recording the location (from GPS) at regular intervals. But the intervals for each device may be different, and because of the inaccuracy of GPS not all points will be on the same line.

Is there a relatively simple way of:
1. Checking to see if a point is close to the line of other points.
2. Producing a set of points that's a combination of the original data.